# showing that some quotient ring is a field.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

To show that $$\mathbb{Z}[x] / \langle 5, x^3+x+1\rangle$$ is a field; I tried to show that $\langle 5, x^3+x+1\rangle$ is a maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Z}[x]$, but I failed.

Because I have not seen the maxmal ideal generated by 2 generateors, the problem is hard.

Please inform me how to show that.

Comment: Have you studied $\mathbb Z_5[x]$? Show that this ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb Z_5[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$

Comment: Yeah. I see. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT: Note that $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle5, x^3+x^2+1\rangle\cong \mathbb{Z}_5[x]/\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle$. Show that $\langle x^3+x^2+1\rangle$ is a maximal ideal in $\mathbb{Z}_5[x]$. Note that it is enough to show that $x^3+x^2+1$ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}_5$, this would imply that the polynomial is irreducible and hence the ideal is maximal.

Comment: @jeong Notice how pritam's solution passes the question from a ring you seem to be less familiar with ($\Bbb Z[x]$) to a "nicer" one, a polynomial ring over a field. Those isomorphism theorems sure are handy!

Comment: Then, one more question. Do you know the structure of $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle5, x^2+1, x^3+x+1\rangle$

Comment: I mean whether the quotient ring $\mathbb{Z}[x]/\langle5, x^2+1, x^3+x+1\rangle$ is field

Comment: That ring is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_5(\sqrt {-1})[x]/\langle x^3+x+1\rangle$. So, you have to show that $x^3+x+1$ has no root in $\mathbb{Z}_5(\sqrt{-1})$

Comment: Grreat!! Thanks a lot!

Comment: The polynomial is $x^3+x+1$, not $x^3+x^2+1$. Not that it makes a difference in the argument.

Answer (score 2):

the most general case, which basically has the same proof (try it!) as what pritam and Thomas Andrews wrote, is

**Theorem:** An ideal in $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ is maximal iff it is of the form $\;\langle\,p\,,\,f(x)\,\rangle\;$ , with $\;f(x)\in\Bbb Z[x]\;$ s.t. $\;f(x)\pmod p\in\Bbb F_p[x]\;$ is irreducible, $\;p\;$ a prime .

Since $\;x^3+x+1\in\Bbb F_5[x]\;$ is irreducible we're done.

Comment: I understand the 'only if' part but, why does the 'if' part hold?

Comment: Do you assume that $p$ is a prime?

Comment: Yes, it is a prime.

Comment: But why does the IF part hold?

Comment: Just mimic the proof offered by pritam, @JeongNam-ho...

Comment: Why don't you consider the ideals that have other forms? For example, <f(x),g(x)>

Comment: Because **I know** what the form of the maximal ideals of $\;\Bbb Z[x]\;$ is, and you will also if you prove the theorem...:)

Comment: I proved the theorem that you say, and I understand. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Suppose you add a polynomial $P(X)$ to your ideal. By multiplying $x^3 + x + 1$ by powers of $x$ and constants, and then and subtracting, you can assume that $P(X)$ is at most cubic. If $P(X)$ is a constant not equal to $5$, it is coprime with $5$ and you get the full ring. If $P(X)$ is quadratic not in the ideal, you can again try a "division algorithm" style argument...

This is admittedly uglier than pritam's wonderful argument, but it's good to see for yourself how you can computationally produce the unit $1 \in R$ by adding any new polynomial.

Comment: At first, I tried this method, but I was very impatient. But you are right! Thank you:)